# Have an object track anothers position with an offset from a third object

Tags: constraints

I have a Spot light that is Tracking To my Camera, but I want it to locate by an offset FURTHER BEHIND an object it is illuminating, so always be located further away and behind that third object.  I.e., always lighting from behind the object toward the camera.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an empty at the origin of you object. Use a track constraint to point the empty at the camera. Parent the spotlight to the empty. The spotlight will stay a fixed distance from object and maintain its relative angle to the camera.

Comment: Thanks and it appears that I also keep the Track To Constraint on the Spotlight towards the Camera.

Comment: You shouldn't need to track the camera with the spotlight, assuming you pointed the spotlight in the correct direction before setting put the parenting?